Issue with BinaryType Data When Writing from S3 to Redshift Using Databricks API in Apache Spark
I encountered an issue while writing data from Amazon S3 to Amazon Redshift using Databricks API in Apache Spark. The issue arises due to a field with a BinaryType in the schema, which causes an exception during the write operation.
When executing the Spark job, I receive the following exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to save StructField(ifAvailable,BinaryType,true) to JDBC

Schema Details:
Here is the schema of the DataFrame being written:
|-- sectorID: string (nullable = true)
|-- cutoffType: string (nullable = true)
|-- moduleIDs: string (nullable = true)
|-- weights: string (nullable = true)
|-- thresholds: integer (nullable = true)
|-- ifAvailable: binary (nullable = true)

I found that the existing code in the RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala file does not handle BinaryType. Here is the relevant section from the https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/redshift/RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala:
Am I looking at the correct Databricks code or this is handled in future releases of Databricks Redshift Connector?
